# Fatou Lemma: Why is $\lim\inf f_n = 0$ where $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, characteristic-functions

In this wildly popular [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242920/tricks-to-remember-fatous-lemma?lq=1), there is a claim:

> I like to remember this by example; specifically let $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$. Then $\lim \inf f_n = 0$, and $\lim \inf \int f_n = 1$.

So $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ is a family of rectangles. I can appreciate that  $\lim \inf \int f_n = 1$ since the area underneath is always $1$ regardless

How do you justify "$\lim \inf f_n = 0$", since $f_n$ maintains a height of $1$ always?

Comment: The second $\liminf$ is taken pointwise.

Comment: $\lim \inf f_n = 0$ means that, for all $x$,  $\lim \inf f_n(x) = 0$.  It is easy to see that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim \inf \chi_{[n,n+1]}(x) =0$.

Comment: @Ramiro What about where $\chi$ is supported?

Comment: $\lim\inf f_n=0$ means that, for all $x$, $\lim\inf f_n(x)=0$. This means: for each FIXED $x$, $\lim\inf f_n(x)=0$.  Now, for each fixed  $x\in \mathbb{R}$, it is easy to see that $\lim\inf \chi_{[n,n+1]}(x)=0$.  One must inspect what happens in each fixed $x$, not mattering what happens in other points. That is why it is called "pointwise (convergence)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point-wise limit of $f_n$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ is $0$. Its limit is a line on the $x$-axis everyhwere except at $\infty$ it is $1$.

Comment: Okay I see. So you have a rectangle situated at say $n =1$, but taking $n \to \infty$ pushes that rectangle to $\infty$ therefore leaving $f = 0$...This is some unusual limit

Comment: yes exactly!...

Comment: Well, still a little weird to think about since it feels like $f$ should never be identically zero...