# why $\lim \inf \int f_n = 1?$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Im posting this problem due to inactive user

taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242922/557708)

Here is the outlines

let $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$. Then $\lim \inf f_n = 0$, and $\lim \inf \int f_n = 1$.

My question is that  why  $\lim \inf \int f_n = 1?$.

**My attempt** :Here $$f_n =\begin{cases} 1 \ \text{if }\ x\in  [n,n+1] \\ 0 \ \text{if} \ x \notin [n, n+1] \end{cases}$$

I can easily see that  inf $f_n=0$  and sup $f_n=1$

Im not getting why  $\lim \inf \int f_n = 1?$.

Comment: What is $\int f_n$?

Comment: ..@Kavi  sir $\int_{X} f_n d\mu$

Comment: What is the integral of the characteristic function of  a set?

Comment: For all $n$ the integral of $f_n$ is equal to $1$. Hence $$\liminf (\int f_n) = \liminf (1) = 1$$

Comment: okk @Kavi sir  u mean $$\int \chi_{[n,n+1]} d\mu = \mu([n,n+1])=n+1-n=1?$$

Comment: Yes, try not to forget definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Try calculating $\int f_n$ for a couple of values of $n$...