# How is summation related with integration?

Tags: integration

How can the following be represented as an integral?

$$\sum_{x=0}^nxP^x$$

I tried:

- $\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^5x=15$
- $\displaystyle\int_1^5x\;dx=12$

Isn't the logic behind both the same? Shouldn't they both give the same result?

I have seen the following thread but I don't seem to understand what is explained. If possible explain in layman's terms:

- [relation between integral and summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184979/relation-between-integral-and-summation)

Comment: The summation $\sum $ is just a short hand notation  for adding things but an integral $\int $ is a limit of a sequence in disguise.

Comment: @Karl Yeah, but that sequence is in the form of a sum. A Riemann sum, to be precise.