# Expected value of #correct tokens when generating a sequence

Tags: probability-distributions, multinomial-coefficients

Let's say I've been given a sentence $\mathcal{S}$of $n$ words. I have a vocabulary $\mathcal M $ of $m$ words. If I sample $n$ words by picking at random from  $\mathcal {M} $ successively what's the expected number of places where the generated words agree with those from  $\mathcal{S}$?

1. If I sample with replacement
2. If I sample without replacement

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following expressions. Wanted to check if they are correct.

\begin{gather}
\sum_{\ell=1}^n \ell \binom n\ell \left(\frac 1m\right)^\ell \left( \frac{m-1}m \right)^{n-\ell} \tag{with replacement} \\
\sum_{\ell=1}^n \ell \binom n\ell \prod_{j=0}^{\ell-1} \frac{1}{m-j} \prod_{i=0}^{n-\ell-1} \frac{-1+m-\ell-i}{m-\ell-i} \tag{without replacement}
\end{gather}

Answer (score 0):

Each word has a probability of $\frac 1m$ of matching.  Hence the expected number of matches is $\frac nm$. As expectation is linear (with no assumption on independence), this is the answer regardless of whether you replace or not.

Just as an illustration:  Suppose $m=2=n$.  Let's suppose the words are $A,B$ and that the given sentence $S$ is $AB$.

With replacement:  the random sentence can be $\{AA,AB,BA,BB\}$ each with probability $\frac 14$.  The respective match scores are $\{1, 2,0,1\}$ so the expected number of matches is $\frac 14\times \left(1+2+0+1\right)=1$.

Without replacement:  the random sentence can be $\{AB,BA\}$ each with probability $\frac 12$.  The respective match scores are $\{2,0\}$ so the expected number of matches is $\frac 12\times \left(2+0\right)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation. Can you elaborate "As expectation is linear (with no assumption on independence), this is the answer regardless of whether you replace or not."

Comment: @HrishikeshGanu   [Linearity of Expectation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184965/what-is-linearity-of-expectations) is a wonderful thing.  Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ generated word.  Thus $X_i=1$ if the $i^{th}$ generated word matches the one in $S$, and $X_i=0$ if it doesn't.  Then the expected number of matches is $E=E[\sum X_i]=\sum E[X_i]=np$ where $p$ is the probability that a given word matches (so $p=\frac 1m$).  At no point do I care whether or not the $X_i$ are independent variables.  With replacement they  are independent, without they are not.

Comment: Got it. That's what allows you to move the $E$ in under the $\sum$? And I guess you can't do the same thing for variance ?

Comment: No, you can't.  though you can write the variance of $X$ as $E[X^2]-\left(E[X]\right)^2$ and, sometimes, that helps.

Comment: One question-you are assuming that $E[X_{1}]$= $E[X_{2}]$ if there are two words. However if I sequentially generate the words then the pdf for $X_{1}$ will be $P(X_{1}=1)=1/m$ and for $X_{2}$ will be $P(X_{2}=1)=1/(m-1)$ since the number of options is reduced by 1 because words can't repeat.

Comment: Nope.  If you sample the entire sentence, the probability for each word to match (taken as a separate variable) is $\frac 1m$.  Why should the second word have a greater chance of matching then the first?

Comment: Go through my explicit examples carefully.  You'll see that the probability of any given word matching is independent of its location in the sentence.  And that it is $\frac 1m$ regardless of replacement.  Work the case of $n=2,m=3$ explicitly...both with and without replacement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45418/discussion-between-hrishikesh-ganu-and-lulu).

Comment: Sorry, I don't go into char rooms.  Just work a bunch of explicit examples...only way to get insight.

Comment: I can see it now. In the example that you gave, P(1st word is correct)= 1/2 and P(2nd word is correct)= P(1st word=B).0 + P(1st word $\neq$B).P(2nd word=B| 1st word $\neq$ B). Hence P(2nd word is correct)= $0+(1/2)(1)$